# How to throw out outliers in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

I'm using STDDEV, but because some of my ranges are small and drastic, I'm getting stuff like

```
AVG: 10  SD: 300
```

The data I'm using is elapsed time (converted to seconds), so this SD should not be possible.

Instead I'd like to be able to remove the outliers from consideration.

For instance, here's a set of data:

```
0,150,150,200,100,155,202,99,140,5000
```

The SD is 1400, and the average is 619. We can see this is heavily skewed by 5000.

Is there a way to remove 5000 from STDDEV?

---

EDIT: There is another wrinkle to this that I forgot to mention that seems to be affecting the answers here: The table contains process runs. So I need to perform all this on a calculation, and grouped by the process.

```
PROC_ID| runId | start | end
-----------------------------
   1   |   1   |   ts  |  ts
   2   |   2   |   ts  |  ts
   2   |   3   |   ts  |  ts
   1   |   4   |   ts  |  ts
  16   |   5   |   ts  |  ts
```

So the value is `end-start`, Grouped by procId. This is how I get the Mode of each Process:

```
SELECT p.PROC_ID, STATS_MODE(ROUND((end - start)*24*60*60)) as mo
  FROM PROC p
  LEFT JOIN PROC_STAT ps ON ps.PROC_ID = p.PROC_ID
  GROUP BY p.PROC_ID
  ;
```

So the outliers aren't for the whole table, but each proc.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem with the calculation of the `STDDEV` is that your data is **not** *normally distributed*, so interpreting the `SD` has little meaning.

You may want to switch to calculate the `median` (which is resistent to outliers)  instead of `avg` and to cut the 5% of the data on the both ends (you may want to adjust the percentage) using `percentile_cont`.

The query below shows the threshols for the lower and upper 2,5% of the data, that can be used for the filter of outlier.

```
select 
 value,
 median(value) over() as med,
 percentile_cont(.975) within group (order by value) over() as perc_hi,
 percentile_cont(.025) within group (order by value) over() as perc_low
from dt; 


     VALUE        MED    PERC_HI   PERC_LOW
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0        150    3920,45     22,275
        99        150    3920,45     22,275
       100        150    3920,45     22,275
       140        150    3920,45     22,275
       150        150    3920,45     22,275
       150        150    3920,45     22,275
       155        150    3920,45     22,275
       200        150    3920,45     22,275
       202        150    3920,45     22,275
      5000        150    3920,45     22,275
```

So excluding the outmost 5% of the data will eliminate the 0 and 5000.

Comment: YES! Thanks so much. I have been looking for a way to use median for standard deviation, but kinda gave up. Edit: Now I see this is not stddev based on media, would you mind updating the answer to show how to get stddev from this?

Comment: Well I'd remove the outlier and than recalculate STDDEV if you need it @TravisHeeter. If you need a founded answer ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The only problem I have now is I need to group by proc_id because the table has many proccess runs in it, and I need it per proc. But it doesn't seem to like me using group by.

Comment: @TravisHeeter pls, open a new question with a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out whatever is above your threshhold of what's reasonable:

```
SELECT AVG(myvalue),
       STDDEV(myvalue)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE myvalue < 1000
```

Or maybe always drop the highest value:

```
SELECT AVG(myvalue),
       STDDEV(myvalue)
  FROM (SELECT myvalue,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myvalue DESC) rev_seq
          FROM mytable)
 WHERE rev_seq > 1
```

Or maybe drop anything more than 5x the average:

```
SELECT AVG(myvalue),
       STDDEV(myvalue)
  FROM (SELECT myvalue,
               myvalue / AVG(myvalue) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) pct_of_average
          FROM mytable)
 WHERE pct_of_average < 5
```

Lots of options, depending on what makes sense for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the mean and standard deviation using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       AVG(value) OVER () AS avg_value,
       STDDEV(value) OVER () AS stddev_value
FROM   table_name t
```

Which outputs:

| VALUE | AVG_VALUE | STDDEV_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 150 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 150 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 200 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 100 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 155 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 202 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 99 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 140 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |
| 5000 | 619.6 | 1540.20880258345347360738482511640400782 |

Then, if you want to find the rows that are within two standard deviations of the mean then you can filter using an inline view and then regenerate the mean and standard deviation over just those rows:

```sql
SELECT value,
       ROUND(AVG(value) OVER (), 2) AS avg_value,
       ROUND(STDDEV(value) OVER (), 2) AS stddev_value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         AVG(value) OVER () AS avg_value,
         STDDEV(value) OVER () AS stddev_value
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  value BETWEEN avg_value - 2 * stddev_value
                 AND avg_value + 2 * stddev_value
```

Which outputs:

| VALUE | AVG_VALUE | STDDEV_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 150 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 150 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 200 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 100 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 155 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 202 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 99 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 140 | 132.89 | 61.54 |

If you still want all the results then you can remove the filter and use conditional aggregation inside the analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT value,
       ROUND(
         AVG(
           CASE
           WHEN value BETWEEN avg_value - 2 * stddev_value
                          AND avg_value + 2 * stddev_value
           THEN value
           END
         ) OVER (),
         2
       ) AS avg_value,
       ROUND(
         STDDEV(
           CASE
           WHEN value BETWEEN avg_value - 2 * stddev_value
                          AND avg_value + 2 * stddev_value
           THEN value
           END
         ) OVER (),
         2
       ) AS stddev_value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         AVG(value) OVER () AS avg_value,
         STDDEV(value) OVER () AS stddev_value
  FROM   table_name t
);
```

Which outputs the same mean and standard deviation but includes all the rows:

| VALUE | AVG_VALUE | STDDEV_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 150 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 150 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 200 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 100 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 155 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 202 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 99 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 140 | 132.89 | 61.54 |
| 5000 | 132.89 | 61.54 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yarrDpw3)